# USB Ethernet device not connecting

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I have a USB Ethernet Device that when I connect to several Ubuntu 18.04 machines (fresh install) it attaches fine. For example I see it as a network interface

```
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:30:f8:52:01:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::b430:f8ff:fe52:176/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the dmesg log when I plug in the device to a working setup:

```
[   66.350555] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   66.451897] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1cf2, idProduct=a4a2, bcdDevice= 3.14
[   66.451918] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   66.451931] usb 1-1.2: Product: RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget
[   66.451944] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.14.70-fslc+g34b9927 with 2184000.usb
[   66.519502] cdc_eem 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_eem' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2, CDC EEM Device, b6:30:f8:52:01:76
[   66.521772] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_eem
```

However, when I attach the device to a Nvidia Jetson running Ubuntu 18.04 it does not show up as an NIC and I get these logs in dmesg (missing device registration):

```
[  153.497340] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using tegra-xusb
[  153.519325] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1cf2, idProduct=a4a2
[  153.519348] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  153.519366] usb 1-2.4: Product: RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget
[  153.519381] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.14.70-fslc+g34b9927 with 2184000.usb
```

Any suggestions or insight on troubleshooting this issue?

Edit:
Results of `sudo dmesg | grep cdc` on a working device:

```
pi@rpi10:~$ sudo dmesg | grep cdc
[91816.165668] cdc_eem 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_eem' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2, CDC EEM Device, ca:33:ae:de:1b:65
[91816.165860] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_eem
pi@rpi10:~$
```

Results of `sudo dmesg | grep cdc` on a **non** working device:

```
jet@jetson10:~$ sudo dmesg | grep cdc 
jet@jetson10:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator This is not a wireless question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep cdc` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks! Edited question per request.

Comment: Plugged into the Jetson; i.e. not working device, what does this report? `sudo modprobe cdc_eem`

Comment: `modprobe: FATAL: Module cdc_eem not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.253-tegra`
So seems I need to install this module. I'm looking into how to do that and will give that a shot.

Comment: On the not working device, run: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` and show us the resukt.

Comment: ```jet@jetson12:~$ sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-4.9.253-tegra' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.```

Comment: 4.9.253-tegra is not an official Ubuntu kernel or flavor. It is highly customized for Jetson devices. I haven't any further suggestions. If this were Ubuntu, I'd say that driver modules are in linux-moduless-extra and to install it. Sorry.